# Condition for two elements XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have an XML with the node `REPORT_TYPE`:

```
<INTERVENTIONSET>
  <REPORT_TYPE>DATE</REPORT_TYPE>
</INTERVENTIONSET>
```

I want to check when the content of `REPORT_TYPE` element is `DATE` or `ORDER` and if so, do something.

Right now it is only comparing for one value:

Demo

I've tried to do some things but they didn't work:

```
<xsl:when test="INTERVENTIONSET/REPORT_TYPE = 'DATE' or 'ORDER'">
```

Or:

```
<xsl:when test="(INTERVENTIONSET/REPORT_TYPE = 'DATE') or (REPORT_TYPE = 'ORDER')">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:when test="INTERVENTIONSET/REPORT_TYPE = 'DATE' or INTERVENTIONSET/REPORT_TYPE = 'ORDER'">
```

**may** work, depending on your current context.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
<xsl:when test="INTERVENTIONSET/REPORT_TYPE[. = 'DATE' or . = 'ORDER']">
```